# Chartjs - add image with rounded border as point

Tags: chart.js, rounded-corners

I've been playing with chartjs for some time now and I can't figure this out.
I'm trying to put an image with a rounded border around it as a point,
like this:
[image]

I manage to add image as point via "pointStyle", but styling won't show.
I manage to add canvas as point via "pointStyle", but then it's not placed right on the chart.
Any idea?
I really appreciate any help on this!
thanks

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: already solved this by using canvas in the correct way.

Comment: @DavidFischer can you elaborate on the solution so that others can benefit...

Comment: WOW sorry mate, this was a long time a go :)

Comment: If I remember correctly I overridden the draw method of the chart and added this rounded image on spot...